# texel density in Blender to Substance Painter

Tags: uv-image-editor

I want to increase the Texel Density for an object -in order to make painting sharper and high resolution- before exporting it to Substance Painter.

But when I unwrapped the object and created new image -in the UV/Image editor- with a resolution of 4K or even 8K I didn't see any gain in resolution in Substance Painter ,

while if I increased the UV map size -by pressing S in the image editor- I get a gain in resolution in Substance Painter, But the problem with this method is that the you can't paint the parts of the UV map outside the 0-1 range in Substance Painter .

Result in Substance Painter
[image: Result in Substance Painter]

Result in Substance Painter with scaled UV map
[image: Result in Substance Painter with scaled UV map]

Comment: Did you create a texture in blender or only the mesh and the UV map?

Comment: When you say you "But when I unwrapped the object and give it image resolution of 4K or even 8K", do you mean you change the document/export resolution within Substance painter? Or did you do something else? Changing the doc/export res within substance painter is the proper way to do this.

Comment: @WannaKnow only the mesh and UV map

Comment: @JtheNunja no, i mean in blender in UV/image editor when i unwrapped the object i create a new image and give it 4K resolution

Comment: That does not affect Substance Painter, it uses its own maps. You need to change your texel resolution in Substance Painter itself. Either in the actual document size, or by selecting a different resolution when exporting.